# clean JS code in multiple files instead of one

Tags: javascript, file, program-entry-point

I write simple canvas game in Js, I have around 700 lines of code and would like to
separate it for more clarity. I want to have one main game loop js file and other files with class and etc. My question is that how I make them connected so the main game loop file could use the other classes and functions from other files??

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/3855179. Also typescript might help too

Answer (score 0):

You can use  in the html of your game and that would import the code directly into your html as one main script. Also remember to replace filename.js with your filename.

Comment: How do I do that? What's the name of that solution? I tried modules and error ocures using it and I would need to do a live server for that to work.

Comment: Basically in the html of the web page you could put something like <script src="scriptname.js" type="module"></script> and in that thing you could do import {import} from "anotherscriptname.js"; and in anotherscriptname.js do export default class [WHATEVER THE INPUT NAME IS].